# An exercise on Galois Connections

Tags: universal-algebra, galois-connections

From "An invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions" of George M. Bergman.

> (i) Let $X$ be a set, $S = T = P(X)$, the set of all
>   subsets of $X$, and let $R$ be the relation of having nonempty
>   intersection. Since this is a symmetric relation, the two closure
>   operators it induces are the same. Show that this operator $∗∗$ takes $A \subseteq P(X)$ to the set of those subsets of $X$ that contain a member of $A$.
>   Deduce that under this Galois connection, the closed sets which are
>   completely join-irreducible (cannot be written as a finite or infinite
>   join of strictly smaller closed sets) are in natural one-to-one
>   correspondence with the elements of $P(X)$, and that the general closed
>   sets are precisely the unions of such closed sets.
>
> (ii) Suppose $X$ is a
>   topological space, $S = T = \{ open \ subsets \ of \ X \}$, and again let $R$ be the
>   relation of having nonempty intersection. Can you characterize the
>   resulting closure operator in this case? Can you get analogs of the
>   remaining statements of part (i)?

I can't understand what (i) is meaning with "the operator $∗∗$ takes $A \subseteq P(X)$ to the set of those subsets of  that contain a member of ". For example taking $X=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $A=\{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}\}$. Every element of $A^*$ must contain an element of the the intersection of all the elements of $A$, so must contain $2$. $A^*=\{\{2\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{1, 2, 3\}, \{2, 3, 4\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \}$ and $A^{**}=A^*$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your set $A^*$ is missing three sets. The set $\{1,3\}$ is $R$-related to both elements of $A$, so $\{1,3\}\in A^*$. Similarly, $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2,4\}$ also belong in $A^*$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was completely wrong, as soon as I can I will try to complete the exercise.